# Optimize SQLite table for 2 different searches

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table that's about 30 million rows by 500 columns.  Three of those columns are:

```
CREATE TABLE core (
state TEXT,
year INTEGER,
randInt INTEGER,
);
```

My primary use for this table is to `SELECT` subsets, either by `state`-`year` pairs or by comparison with `randInt`.  `randInt` is a random integer that ranges from 0 to 100.

Examples of state-year selection:

```
SELECT * WHERE state='MA' AND year=1999;
SELECT * WHERE (state='MA' AND year=1999) OR (state='NJ' AND year=1998);
```

Examples of randInt selection:

```
SELECT * WHERE randInt < 10;
SELECT * WHERE randInt = 10;
```

These two types of selections comprise more than 95% of the database queries I will be doing.  Is there any way to optimize the table specifically for them?

I guess I want to explicitly `CREATE INDEX` for `randInt` and a compound index for `state,year`, but I don't know if having one interferes with the other, and I don't know how to create compound indices.

Should I turn off indexing on all the other 497 columns, since I will rarely if ever index over them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an index for one column has no effect on the other indices. Note however that SQLite uses at most one index during a query (not an issue in your case).

Also, if you have not created indexes for other 497 columns then you do not need to 'turn indexing off' for them. Indexes take space and require time to update when the table is updated, so it would be a disaster to have 497 indices you do not need.

To create an index on two columns you need to execute something like:

```
CREATE INDEX indyearstate ON tbl (year,state)
```

Comment: My understanding was that indices are created by default in SQLite.  I could definitely be mistaken, though.  Also, if I can have at most a single index, should I create a combined state-year column (e.g. concatinate them together)?  I'd definitely be willing to do so if it would speed up the `SELECT`s even 10%.

Comment: I was thinking of saying that. If you plan many queries I would suggest having a yearstate column with integer indicating both year and state. For example (year*100 + state_number). Indexing this variable would be much simple for SQLite.

Comment: Oh, and an index on two columns is still a single index. I was just saying that if you have an index for (year,state) and an index for (randInd) then only one of them would be used in any query, not both.

Comment: By default SQLite creates only one index - for the rowid variable. Most often (by default) it is an invisible integer column that is unique for every row in the database.

Comment: Ok.  So I concatenate `state` and `year`, `CREATE INDEX` on that and on `randInt`, and then things are magically faster, or do I have to run a different SELECT query?  Do I have to rebuild the index each time I add data or the database takes care of that automagically?

Comment: Yes, database takes care of indexes automagically. Once you created an index it requires no care or attention from you.

Comment: The database engine will automatically decide which indexes to use for your SELECT queries. So once you create proper indexes your queries should run faster.

Comment: That definitely helps.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should create two indices:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_1 ON core(year, state);
CREATE INDEX IX_2 ON core(randInt);
ANALYZE; -- ask SQLite to analyze data and update "stats" table on indices
```

Since then your queries will run (significantly) faster and you shouldn't do anything to update indices: SQLite will keep them up-to-date (until the time you manually drop the indices via "DROP INDEX").

You can also try this index instead of IX_1:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_1a ON core(state, year);
```

If your core table has more different "states" then "years" this index can speed up things a bit more.

Comment: +1 for ANALYZE.  More different years than states actually, so I'll stick with `(year,state)`.

Comment: As I understand, `ANALYZE` is helpful only if you run queries with `JOIN`. Does no harm though.

Comment: ANALYZE helps on any query that has WHERE condition which can be optimized with an index. Even if you select from a single table without JOINs.